# View pager showing incorrect result

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I am using View pager with pager sliding strip to update data in a grid view. When first opened grid view shows result of screen 2 on both first and second screen and after two three swipes it comes to original state. This is my code. Please help what i am doing wrong.

Pager Adapter

```
public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
        List<String> tabtitle, int count) {
    super(fm);
    PAGE_COUNT = count;
    tabTitles = tabtitle;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return TabFragment.newInstance(position);

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles.get(position);
}
```

Fragment

```
int mPage;
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
public static TabFragment newInstance(int position) {
    TabFragment frag = new TabFragment();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_PAGE, position);
    frag.setArguments(b);
    return frag;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabsfrag, container, false);
```

tried to access mpage with static and non static ways but result stays same.

Comment: Ahmed, it isn't clear to me what the problem is can you edit the question?

Comment: @MarkGilchrist its like if i have A,B,C screen. B,B,C appears in view pager below sliding tab

Comment: Have you logged the get instance method to see if you are passing 0, 1, 2  for screen a b c. Can you post the function that build the page